# Cocoa: Custom control not limited to window frame - how to start?

Tags: cocoa, controls

I want to build a custom control that would work like this:
You have a kind of NSButton with an image. 
You click the button and than appears a big square with a grid of photos.
You click one of the photos and it is set up as new image for the button. (square dissapears)

Now, how to draw this big square with photos if I want it not to be limited to window frame?
I mean, if the button was close to window border the square is going to be partially outside window. I would also like to add some shadow to the square and an animation for opening/closing.

One important thing: I want to be able to draw not only a square but any other simple shape (circle)!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a drawing question so much as a general custom views question. It's important to make that distinction.

I'll describe this in terms of rectangles to give you the general idea*. You should make sure you understand the [view hierarchy](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy.html) and [view geometry](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html) in Cocoa. Without this important requisite knowledge, you'll remain dead in the water.

It's easy to set an NSButton's image, so I'll leave that to you. Your button's action, however, would tell some controller to show the "image picker" for the given button. Your image picker would be some type of [borderless window](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BorderlessWindow) with an image list inside. The image picker could be an IKImageBrowserView (you'll have to enable Image Kit in Interface Builder for this control to appear), which gives you an iPhoto-like grid of images (with/without titles, different border types, etc.).

An explanation of the operation of this controller and how it creates the window, manages the selection, and sets the button's image is *very broad* so if you get hung up on any of those steps, you'll need to create a ***separate question for each problem***, otherwise this answer would have to be an instruction manual for writing your app for you.

---

* Your problem is a little more difficult because of your desire to have differently-shaped "popup windows" ... you'd have to make sure your available photos fit neatly within the shape so none of them are cut off. Armed with the basic knowledge of view geometry, I'll leave this to you as an exercise. A hint: you can use a borderless, transparent window to host a view that draws itself in [any shape you please](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html).

Comment: Two things: 1. It's worth mentioning that the pop-up window should be a child window of the window that contains the button. That makes it follow the parent window during moves automatically, and keeps them together in Exposé. 2. There is one case in which you may *want* to cut off images: Cutting off the last visible row implies that the list is scrollable. This isn't as important on the Mac (since you have visible scroll bars), but I still occasionally miss the scroll bar on a web page that has content below the fold, so this is worth considering even on the Mac.